# Mouseenter events on absolutely positioned elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a menu that will be several layers deep. My intention is to use several nested UL and LI elements to make this structure. When I mouse over one of the LI elements it shows the next level of navigation for that menu item. When I try to move my mouse to that element, however, it automatically shows me the children of the final menu item.

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a>First</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Child of First</a></li>
                <li><a>Child of First</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>Second</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Child of Second</a></li>
                <li><a>Child of Second</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<style>
    .headerMenu ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        width: 50%;
        background: black;
        color: white;
    }

    .headerMenu ul ul {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 0;
        left: 50%;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .headerMenu ul ul.visibleSub {
        width: 100%;
        opacity: 1;
    }
</style>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $ul = $('.headerMenu ul');

        $ul.find('li').on({ 
            mouseenter: function() {
                $(this).find('ul').first().addClass('visibleSub');
            },
            mouseleave: function() {
                $(this).find('ul').first().removeClass('visibleSub');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can see and demo the very stripped down code at https://codepen.io/pcasagrande/pen/RZqQwO

Comment: That's a list sibling, not child. You should be able to achieve this effect using just CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add z-index: -1 for unvisible ul:

```
   .menu ul ul {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 0;
        left: 50%;
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    .menu ul li:hover > ul{
       opacity: 1;
       width: 100%;
       z-index: 1;
    }
```

Also as I mention above you can avoid jquery and do this with pure css. 
Also you can add some transition for `.menu ul ul{ transition: .2s}` and it will have sime kind of simple animation.

Comment: The z-index fixed it. The menus actually do have CSS animations which I stripped out to simplify the code I was sharing. The JS is needed for some other stuff much more than just the mouse over stuff. Thank you for the fix!

Answer (score 1):

It is the fact you use `opacity` to hide the second layer of menu's. They are still there, and you hover over the second set when you move there, so it's made visible. If you use `display` to really hide the second layer it will work. Change your CSS to:

```
.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 50%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.menu ul ul {
  display: none;      
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  left: 50%;
}

.menu ul ul.visibleSub {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

Nothing else needs to change.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need animation, you can use `display: hidden` instead of `opacity: 0`

Because in your code, although the second level `li a` links are not visible, they have padding/margin and actually occupies space on the right side of the first level `ul`.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/prQapW